# JavaScript: Refer to remaining Array in the reduce method (fold)?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, fold

I want to test wether an Array consists only of unique elements and my solution is the following:

```
function uniqueElements(a) {
  var r = true;
  while (a) {
    var [el, a] = [a.slice(0,1), a.slice(1)];
    r &= !a.includes(el);
  };
  return !!r;
}
```

This method works. However, since I am adopting a more functional style, and because folds are awesome, I would like to implement a function which looks somewhat like this:

```
function uniqueElements(a) {
  var isUnique = (acc, el) => acc &= !remainingArray.includes(el);
  return a.reduce(isUnique, true);
}
```

I can't figure out how to get to that `remainingArray` variable. Does anybody know how to get it? Is this even possible in JS, and if not, how could that function be expressed through a fold?

Comment: You could accept a third and fourth argument, e.g. `(acc, el, index, array)`, then use something like `array.slice(index)`. But a uniqueness test is better implemented with an object that acts as a hashmap where the keys are the array elements.

Comment: or .. you can just `return a.length === new Set(a).size;` and be done with it :]

Comment: You can use `indexOf` instead of `includes` - it takes a start position as an optional arguments

Comment: @Bergi `includes` also has an optional argument as `fromIndex`.

Comment: @themefield Oh, you're right! I misremembered, `find` and `findIndex` lack this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember not to get stuck in a pattern of thinking. Folds are great but in JavaScript there's no way to stop folding early if our result can be computed before traversing the entire array

In other words, what is the answer of the following? `true` or `false`?

```
uniqueElements ( [ 1 , 1 , 2 , 3 , ... thousands more items ] )
// => true or false ?
```

We can determine the answer to be `false` immediately after processing the second `1`. There's no need to keeping folding in `2`, or `3`, or the rest of the array as they will not affect the `false` outcome

A possible solution is a simple recursive procedure

```js
const isUnique = ([ x, ... xs ], set = new Set ()) =>
  x === undefined
    ? true
    : set.has (x)
      ? false // we already found a non-unique, stop recurring
      : isUnique (xs, set.add (x))
      
console.log (isUnique ([]))
// true

console.log (isUnique ([ 1, 2, 3 ]))
// true

console.log (isUnique ([ 1, 1, 2, 3 ]))
// false
```

Or a stack-safe solution that still maintains a pure functional interface – if I had to guess, this is probably 10x faster than the above program and doesn't expose private API

```js
const isUnique = xs =>
  {
    const set = new Set ()
    for (const x of xs)
      if (set.has (x))
        return false
      else
        set.add (x)
    return true
  }

console.log (isUnique ([]))
// true

console.log (isUnique ([ 1, 2, 3 ]))
// true

console.log (isUnique ([ 1, 1, 2, 3 ]))
// false
```

Or make up your own solution – either way, just don't get cornered into thinking folds need to be used wherever your touch a traversable data structure.

And in a more general sense, you need to practice imagining what the process of your function looks like. I recommend that you play compiler/evaluator with a pencil and paper while you're first getting the hang of it. Eventually you will be able to envision simple processes in your head; and then more complex ones with practice over time – I say this because you probably wouldn't have reached for a fold to complete this task if you could see how silly it looks to continue folding *after* the result can be returned

On that note, that is why I used `Set` to check for uniques as opposed to `.includes`. Sets can do binary search whereas array searches are linear – looking for your item in an array one-by-one just seems silly once you can see what that process would look like for a significantly large input. Only when you're envisioning process can you see how alternative data structures like Set can dramatically lower the time complexity of your function

Answer (score 0):

You could slice the array:

```
function isUnique(xs) {
  return xs.reduce((acc, x, i) => {
    if (xs.slice(i + 1).includes(x)) {
      return false;
    }
    return acc;
  }, true);
}
```

Although, as mentioned in the comments, you could also use a hash for better performance if you have strings or numbers in your array.